# Can I use latest stable TypeScript or should I stick with the version shipped with AngularCLI?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I wasn't able to find any official recommendation about whether or not upgrade the TypeScript version using the latest stable version available.

The npm version is automatically set in `package.json` by AngularCLI when creating a new project. It currently is:

`"typescript": "~2.4.2"`

which means latest `2.4.x` version. I was wondering if it would be possible to use the latest stable TypeScript version (and what would be the implications), for example `2.5.x`.

Is there a specific reason for setting `~2.4.2` and not `"^2.4.2` (which means latest `2.x.x` version).

Comment: Have you considered running your tests with the newer version to find out? What newer features are you looking to use?

Comment: yes and in my case all tests are passing, no need of specific new features

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE 2021**:
Checkout this answer [Is there a compatibility list for Angular / Angular-CLI and Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js/60258560#60258560)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
Angular cli may not always support the latest version of TypeScript.
There is some issues and PR's related to that:

- [Support TypeScript 2.4+](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7578)
- [Typescript 2.4 support](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6827)
- [feat(@angular/cli): support TypeScript 2.4](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/7065)

Also bare in mind that the latest TypeScript version might not be compatible with your Angular version.

If you want to jump to a new/latest TypeScript version - it is at your own risk. Once you do so you have to make sure that it is not breaks anything like tests(`ng t`), prod build(`ng build --prod`), etc.

> If you stick to the default cli TypeScript version you - are safe.

**UPDATE 09 Sept 2017**: For anyone who care about using the cli with the latest TypeScript checkout this recent [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7625) and this particular [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7625#issuecomment-328174683) as there was a `TypeScript version warning logic` introduced in the latest cli `1.4`. [Here is what](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/022ed2ce71b83192d8a8185ec77e71ae939a4e54/packages/%40angular/cli/upgrade/version.ts#L169) it is based on(angular cli team recommendation):

```
 const versionCombos = [
      { compiler: '>=2.3.1 <3.0.0', typescript: '>=2.0.2 <2.3.0' },
      { compiler: '>=4.0.0 <5.0.0', typescript: '>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' },
      { compiler: '>=5.0.0 <6.0.0', typescript: '>=2.4.0 <2.6.0' }
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change/ update but make sure you follow every release for support and updates. Every release it will change.

I use the very latest typescript version and never faced a problem so far.

**UPDATE:**

Since Angular [1.4](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.4.0) angular-cli reports the required typescript version while serve, build and version check

Example:

> @angular/compiler-cli@4.3.6 requires typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' but 2.4.2 was found instead.
>   Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.
>
> Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

```
npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'
```

> To disable this warning run "ng set --global warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".

Comment: Sorry. I was about to mention releases

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command in your Terminal or Command prompt when you get this Message
(Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.)
(npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0')

> **npm install -g typescript**