# Is nestjs compatible to typescript 3.x?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm starting a project with Nestjs, in one of its [samples](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/02-gateways/package.json) the version of typescript is 2.8, but typescript's latest version is 3.2. Is nest.js compatible to version 3.x of typescript?

Comment: This is the type of question that usually gets down voted and even closed on SO because it isn't a question about coding.  Looks like you are just getting started here.  As you'll learn, SO isn't for all questions.

Comment: I disagree. This is *not* an opinion-based question but rather about version compatibility. If you search SO for similar questions you'll find loads of (upvoted, hence considered useful) threads, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46030459/4694994

Comment: @KimKern Could you please edit the question so that it is clearly about version compatability and not recommendations? I'd do it myself but I'm not au fait with the tech involved.

Comment: @StephenKennedy Good point. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the latest Typescript version. Typescript 3.x support was added in this [pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/1322). I'd recommend using the [nest CLI](https://docs.nestjs.com/) to setup a new project.