# Unable to downgrade angular cli to 1.0.0-Beta.24

Tags: angular, web, angular-cli

I am new to angular, I want to run an angular project that uses angular- cli version 1.0.0-beta.24.

I tried uninstalling the current npm version, clean cache and than npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24. but it doesn't work. I am using node version 0.35.1

I have installed node -v v6.0.0 and nvm doesnt work

Comment: please post the errors you received and also the package.json.

Comment: try node version 6.x, see more details on that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60258560/415078

Comment: Please post console errors and logs as text, not as pictures of text. Search engines will not pick up the error message from the picture and no one with the same error will find your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Usually when you are downgrading/upgrading Angular projects you have
>   to make sure that Angular CLI version matches Angular version and
>   Typescript version. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js/60258560#60258560)

In your case if you are downgrading to `1.0.0-beta.24` you have to use `NodeJS v6.x` and make sure you are using `Typescript v2.0.x`

Also, when downgrading versions, make sure you removed `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` files if you have any in your project. Then run `npm i` or `yarn` to pull the old packages.

> If you are having issues switching NodeJS versions try [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

**UPDATE:**
The error you are getting might be related to connectivity issues. If you are behind the proxy try that:

```
npm config set proxy http://your.company.proxy.com:port
npm config set https-proxy http://your.compny.company.com:port
```

Comment: The github link in the above referred link doesnt not work. i used this link https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/ and downloaded file node-v6.17.1-linux-x64.tar.gz i still have 0.35.1 version. I tried curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x |  bash and i get an error can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock i know its because of the sudo rights and i dont have admin permission on my system. Is there any other way it can be done or can you point me to the rights link or resource. Thanks

Comment: `>The github link in the above referred link doesn't not work` - what link?

Comment: @Sarabjeet Just updated the answer with the link to NVM, that should help.

Comment: i have installed node version but nvm doesnt work and angular command also doesnt work to install the beta can u please check the attached screenshot in the question.

Comment: this is the package.json file{
  "version": "3.8.6",
  "name": "npm",
  "description": "a package manager for JavaScript",
  "keywords": [
    "install",
    "modules",
    "package manager",
    "package.json"
  ],
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "config": {
    "publishtest": false
  },
  "homepage": "https://docs.npmjs.com/",
  "author": "Isaac Z. Schlueter <i@izs.me> (http://blog.izs.me)",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/npm/npm"
  },

Comment: for my project which is on angular 1.0.0-beta.24, package.json looks like this{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --env=prod --base-href=/paper-archive/ --prod --aot=false",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },

Comment: @Sarabjeet The error you are getting saying there is a problem with connectivity. Are you behind the proxy? - if so see my update on the answer.

Comment: is it not required to have the nvm to install angular version the jar file for v6.0.0 has only npm and node

Comment: @Sarabjeet yes nvm is not required but it is gives you a flexible way of switching between node versions, it is useful when migrating projects like in your case, that is why I recommend that. Can you confirm you bypass the proxy?

Comment: got it and the package.json file versions also differ i hope thats not an issue i am just trying it now

Comment: please check the screenshot attached i think its still the same issue with proxy and i also dont have sudo access

Comment: @Sarabjeet you should find out your company proxy name

Comment: @kunevic Thanks a lot i have done the proxy settings and than i did npm install -g express (as i was getting error package.json missing)
and than npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24 than i did ng version ---angular-cli 1.0.0-beta24....Finally...i hope my steps are correct but thanks a lot...i will now try to run my angular project and see what happens.

Comment: Error while running the project.
[]$ng serve
You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the serve command.
[]$npm start
> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
You are running version 6.0.0 of Node, which will not be supported in future
versions of the CLI. The official Node version that will be supported is 6.9 and greater.
To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.nodeDeprecation=false".** NG Live Development Server is running on http://0.0.0.0:4200. **
Hash: b8a000d32e50ae915dc8
Time: 26019ms

Comment: chunk    {0} 0.chunk.js, 0.chunk.js.map 30.1 kB {1} {2} {3} {4} [rendered]
chunk    {1} 1.chunk.js, 1.chunk.js.map 34.5 kB {0} {2} {3} {4} [rendered]
chunk    {2} 2.chunk.js, 2.chunk.js.map 36.6 kB {0} {1} {3} {4} [rendered]
chunk    {3} 3.chunk.js, 3.chunk.js.map 35.8 kB {0} {1} {2} {4} [rendered]
chunk    {4} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 710 kB {7} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 295 kB {8} [initial] [rendered]


webpack: Compiled successfully.

Comment: @Sarabjeet do you still have any issues?