# npm start gives "Node.js version 14.9.0 detected" error on windows

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-start

npm start command is giving the following error:

```
Node.js version v14.9.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.15, or v16.10.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

I have tried uninstalling nodejs and reinstalling it again twice but no luck.

```
node -v -> v16.20.0
npm -v -> 8.19.4
```

Please tell me how to resolve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Have yo tried following the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491856/ng-command-is-displaying-incorrect-node-version

Comment: are you using NVM, it also causes problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Node.js v14.15, or v16.10.

You can always do npm install -g node@16.10 or get it directly from the web site  https://nodejs.org/fr/download/releases