# VS Code Debugger Extremely Slow to Reach First Breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using VS Code on Windows 10, to debug both Python and React. The debugger is extremely slow to reach the first breakpoint, for **both** Python and JS/Chrome. The sequence of actions I'm observing is:

1. VS Code's program tab lights up immediately

[image]

2. The **first breakpoint** only gets reached/highlighed **10-60 seconds later**. In between it hangs. I try to click anywhere on the screen but the application is frozen.

[image]

Extensions installed:

[image]

About:

[image]

Comment: Try to enable in your launch.json:
"logging": { "engineLogging": true }

Comment: I did, where is it being written to?

Comment: A bunch of messages should appear in `Debug console`. Is there anything among these entries to explain the delay?

Comment: No, there is nothing new in the console.

Comment: I have the same issue with debugging Angular Code in Chrome. VS Code takes some time to hit any breakpoint. Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: No. Still waiting for any leads. I might have to re-install VS and see what happens.

Comment: @mor222 try grabbing & moving the title bar, as I posted below.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: 2021-09-11, VSC **1.60.0**, still the same.

Comment: "Try to enable in your launch.json: "logging": { "engineLogging": true }"
https://gist.github.com/rakkarage/e716a6b0e01016a84fc65622a8125f38
debugging godot on ubuntu takes 45 seconds to hit first breakpoint but rest fine... i think it was faster on windows tho i am probably doing something wrong

Answer (score 17):

This is a VS Code bug (one that I just spent hours diagnosing until I stumbled upon the workaround lol).

See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123257?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Current workaround until May fix apparently:

Need to set the following in settings.json in VS Code

**debug.focusWindowOnBreak: false**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y223f.png

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution because my VS application icon doesn't light up. But if I go back to VS I see that the breakpoint is yellow and ready. In the alternative approach (grab/move title bar), the VS application icon does light up, I just need to move the VS window to see the breakpoint. Seems like this issue was temporarily fixed in June/July, and now it came back in the latest VS release.

Comment: This is a perfect solution for me because I absolutely hate that windows doesn't allow me to disable screen jacking - this is a perfect 2 birds 1 stone fix for me

Answer (score 11):

It looks like I found something that speeds it up. If I **grab and move the title bar** of VS Studio, the breakpoint gets reached and highlighted.

This is a preliminary finding, I'll edit it if I find something else.

[image]

Comment: Works for me but so weird, VSC can lag up to 30 seconds but F12 is right away!

Comment: Works for me. That is really strange.  VSC v1.62.1

Comment: Its worked for me also! I've to move the window

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved similar issue, just for your reference.

- Issue: When I try to debug node.js + angular application, the
  debugger takes very long time when starts node.js server before it reaches to the 1st breakpoint.
- Reason: VS code scans all the JS files for a source map to typescript
  files.
- Solution: In the launch.json configure "outFiles" to point to the JS
  files that you want to debug as .ts only.

Example:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Node",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server/server.js",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeArgs": ["--inspect-brk"],
    "runtimeExecutable": "node",
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/server/lib/dist/*.js"
    ],
    "skipFiles": [
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I collapsed  the "watch" panel (on the left side of a window) and removed all the variables. After this a speed (in debug mode) has been  increased much!