# Compiling Angular again and again

Tags: angular, typescript

I use Angular 7. I am using **ng serve --aot -o** command to compile my project.

Until now all has worked perfectly. However, suddenly I am suffer an error that say:
"FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory."
I have tried to increase the space-size: **--max-old-space-size=8192.**
But without success, it does not stop compiling.

This is not a memory problem. The problem is that it says compiling over and over again. The error only happens to me and not to my partners.

It works well for all my colleagues. I have tried :

1. Reinstalling node
2. Removing node_modules
3. Clearing cache node
4. Checking versions compared to my mates
5. Cloned the project

Comment: Check you node version and try to install the correct one for Angular 7, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: and please share your tsconfig.json

Comment: @pc_coder tsconfig is part of the project, peers have it working and he re-cloned, so its not that, i'd place my bet on the environment binaries. that is cli itself or node or such

Comment: @Stavm I had in the past same problem and for using devextreme with changin spme of tsconfig property I solved problem. That is why I asked.

Comment: afaik, this has been an error due to the node version being too low. Try it with node 12.x.x

Comment: It does sound like a memory issue - how are you setting the `max_old_space_size`? Can you try `node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --aot -o`