# Can not run "npm run build" in vue cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-4

I run "npm run build" in my vue project and got this bellow error message：

[image: error message image]

I try add

```
module.exports = {
 css: {
  extract: false
 }
}
```

in my "vue.config.js" file and it can build production file

but only build javascript code , not build css code

so how can I solve this problem?

here is my package.json：

```
{
  "name": "alpha-shop-vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.49.7",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

vue/cli version：4.1.1

node version: v14.16.0

npm version: v6.14.11

windows10

Comment: check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028314/error-node-modules-callback-was-already-called solves your issue

Comment: It solves my problem , thx. Don't know why use "windows cmd" can build the production, but use "git bash" got error message?