# ng is recognized but the ng commands are not executed

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I recently set up my new Window machine and tried configuring node, npm, angular-cli etc. I have done it in many machines in past and afaik I have done the same steps.

However, I have getting this strange behavior from angular cli. The ng command is recognized as can be seen from attached image, but the command is not executed. It keep throwing to me the list of methods available in cli, when I am using one of these methods.

The problem is same for all the methods.

[image]

I know pasting picture is not appreciated here, but in my case there is nothing else I can present.

Have anyone faced such issue ? Please suggest.

Comment: Had something similar last week. Downgraded node to 14.x and npm to 6.6 (I think). Then actually installed cli in the current path separately again (even though it should have been there because of the project. So without global flag npm i @angular/cli - then everything worked again magically..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I created [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22114) in the GitHub about it, and they told me that I should create a Stack Overflow question using the tag `angular-cli`.

So, I did it. I created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879659/angular-cli-v13-can-not-run-ng-commands) and I even put a bounty on it. At first, I couldn't run `ng` command at all. Neither answer solved the problem completely, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880090/14389830) made it run. However, when I run `ng` command, it always just displayed all possible options to call.

### Problem

This is the problem with Angular CLI v13 on Windows.

### Solution

It's not much of the solution, but I downgraded the CLI to v12 and everything worked again. So I recommend this solution until someone figure out how to make it work on Windows for CLI v13.