# Would there ever be a case where we shouldn't use the latest version of node with the latest version Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular

Would there ever be a case where we shouldn't use the latest stable version of `node` with the latest version `Angular`? Whenever I read the `Angular` update guide, there is always a mention of the minimum version of `node` to be used with that version `Angular`. So rather than worrying about using the minimum version of `node`, just use the current stable version.

Are there any drawbacks to doing that?

Comment: Yes you can use latest stable version of node with latest Angular

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that may create a problem here, so **yes**, but...

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60258560/11135174) mentions it, you'll find in [this link](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3) every node version that are safe to use with the version of angular you're using.

[image]