# issue in Updating angular version 12 to 13

Tags: angular, angular12, angular13, angular-upgrade

I have update angular from 12 to 13. After updating that I am getting error in browser console.
Below are steps:

1. npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13(error: peer dependency)
2. npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --force(Sucessfully executed)
3. ng serve

- Getting below error in browser console.

```
    client.min.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
        at client.min.js:55:22
        at client.min.js:54:447
        at client.min.js:53:424
        at Object.69554 (client.min.js:40:434)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
        at Module.52790 (globals.ts:1:8)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
        at Module.7348 (public.component.ts:8:14)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
        at Module.50023 (app.component.ts:17:14)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to update your npm, node and typescript to the latest. I successfully upgraded from 12.0 to 13.3.7.
npm install npm@latest -g
npm install -g typescript@latest

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your node version. Here you can see the [version table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js)

Secondly, Starting from version 12. Angular CLI does not support Protractor for new projects.
For further transition, you need to use additional [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/protractor-to-cypress).