# How to solve Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production node:16120 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm

i tried creating a new angular application **ng new app** and i got this error

```
Node.js version v11.0.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
(node:16120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not supported
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/bootstrap.js:21:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.0.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js:47:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
(node:16120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16120) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i tried uninstalling node and npm and angular and installing them again but got thesame error

Comment: ...use an even-numbered Node.js version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this issue after updating my node version to 19.x. But then I updated my node version to latest stable version and this issue was resolved.
Try updating your node using following steps on this link:

https://codeforgeek.com/update-node-using-npm/

Answer (score 1):

I also faces that issue when i use latest version of angular 15 with existing node version 17.9.0 (ie. 2 step downgrade from latest, no LTS) .

The version of angular should be compatible to certain node version. The most LTS node version support to some extent . For me currently, latest **angular version 15** is compatible with **node version ^14.20.0 || ^16.13.0 || ^18.10.0** (all with LTS) or latest.

For the Reference check out [Question regarding compatibility of angular and node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js)

Source : Check out full list of compatibility among various version of angular, node, typescript and rxjs on [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3)