# How to open/run old angular Project in local host

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to run old project on the team Drive, but I'm not sure what node version I will use. Is there a way for me to check it in the code or using the terminal?

[image]

Another questions:

1. In the READ ME File, it says here that it use Angular CLI version 6.0.3. -- so do I need to use this version?
2. Do I need to update the version of my dependency since this one is an old angular project? If yes, how? What command do I need to use?
3. Is it okay to delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` if I use **npm install**?

This is my whole package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-tool",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.0-next.1",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.0-next.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.0-next.1",
    "@angular/core": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.0-next.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.0-next.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.0-next.1",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.0-next.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^10.1.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.25.2",
    "angular-datatables": "^6.0.1",
    "angular-file-uploader": "^5.0.2",
    "angular-notifier": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.0.0-alpha2",
    "c3": "^0.4.23",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartist": "^0.11.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "d3": "^4.8.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase": "^7.9.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "ng-chartist": "^1.1.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.3.5",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "6.1.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^7.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.10.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "pace-js": "^1.0.2",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.0-next.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.0-next.1",
    "@types/c3": "^0.6.4",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: you can check the angular version compatibility with required node version from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js

to check angular and node version use this command in terminal

 ng --version,

 node --version,

to start an existing project you no need to update the dependencies, you can just start the app using  

ng serve

Comment: I would recommend removing major/minor patching from your package.json so that exact version of packages will be installed.

Comment: @BrandonTaylor how can I do that? I mean how to know the dependencies that are okay to remove? thanks for the recommendation

Comment: In the package.json, `~` represents a major version, `^` represents a minor version. If you keep these characters in your file, npm will automatically patch to the next version available, which can cause incompatibilities between packages. I would recommend removing those to help, but not guarantee, that the packages listed are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 7):

The project is obviously Angular `v8`.

So I would say you should do the following steps:

#### 1. Step - Install newest Angular CLI

Angular CLI will recognize if the project itself is using older version of Angular, so no need to limit yourself to the old version of the CLI.

---

#### 2. Step - Install correct version of the Node.js

For Angular `v8`, you need Node `v10.9`.

**Note:** This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60258560/14389830) have compatibility table, so you can check it once you start upgrading your project.

---

#### 3. Step - Install dependencies

Install all the dependencies with `npm install`.

**Note:** Don't delete `package-lock.json` and do `npm install`. `package-lock.json` keeps the dependency versions and if you delete it and do `npm install`, it can install newer versions, which can break you project.

---

#### 4. Step - Run the project

Run the project with `npm start`.

---

#### 5. Step (Optional) - Upgrade project to latest version

You can now gradually upgrade your app to newer versions. You can check [Angular official guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=8.0-9.0) for upgrading projects.

**Note:** It is recommended to upgrade only one version at a time. So you should first upgrade to `v9`, then to `v10`...

**Note:** When you upgrade Angular project, you should first upgrade all third-party dependencies to the next version. Otherwise, Angular will throw an error when upgrading, if it finds something incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by NeNaD. I just want to add this helpful article that I referred to when I was upgrading my old Angular project, https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/update-angular-cli-version-ng-update-to-latest-6-7-versions/

Comment: The link you provided got all I was looking for, it's a detailed guide. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your questions:

---

1. I'm not sure what node version I will use. Is there a way for me to check it in the code or using the terminal?

---

> You can make use of the node version command as
> `node -v`
> or
> `node --version`

---

2. it says here that it use Angular CLI version 6.0.3. -- so do I need to use this version?

---

> You could look into upgrade options but since its a old version and you are trying to run it. I would recommend to first use the same version as to see how its running and doesn't cause any abnormalities and then you could upgrade as others suggested

---

3. Do I need to update the version of my dependency since this one is an old angular project? If yes, how? What command do I need to use?

---

> I would recommend you do not and so you refer below what is going on.

> Version numbers in semantic versioning consist of 3 sets of numbers separated by a `.`, for example `1.2.3` which represent `major.minor.patch` respectively. The semantic version documentation explains each of these:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.
>    In the `package.json`, for each dependency you will see a corresponding semver number. Sometimes this is prefixed with a carat ^ or tilde ~.
>
> `^1.2.3` — install the latest version of `1.X.X` (don’t go past specified major, only a higher minor and patch number).
>
> `~1.2.3` — install the latest version of `1.2.X` (don’t go past specified major or minor, only a higher patch number).
> You can use range operators (e.g. >=) if you need more fine tuned control of the version range.

---

4. Is it okay to delete the node_modules and package-lock.json if I use npm install?

---

> You can remove the `node_modules` as it will be re-created when you re-install using the package.json but keep in mind that if there have been changes made to the node_modules packages then they might be overwritten but this generally doesn't happen but its good to know.

> Don't delete your `package-lock.json` make a copy of it somewhere. Also, deleting the file can affect your version control.

> ### why?
>
> Imagine the project has a dependency, example-package at version ^1.0.0. This is the latest available version at the time of first install and is added to the lock file as 1.0.0. A month later, a new release of example-package comes out 1.1.0. Let’s pretend a new developer joins your team and clones the project repository, and installs the project.
>
> The version in the package.json is ^1.0.0 (meaning the latest 1.X.X), so you would think that the 1.1.0 would be installed on the new developer’s machine, but this is not the case. When the dependency was first added to the project, 1.1.0 did not exist, so the version listed in the lock file is 1.0.0. **Therefore 1.0.0 will always be installed**, despite there being a newer available version that meets the semantic version specification in the package.json.
>
> If you do not commit the lock file to your repository, or delete the lock file and reinstall your node modules, then version 1.1.0 of example-package will be installed, since it will be treated as if this is the first time installing. New bugs could have been introduced into 1.1.0, or the maybe the package dependencies changed and are incompatible with other dependencies in your project.
>
> This is how deleting the lock file can unintentionally cause dependencies to be upgraded which can break your application.