# Error: Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'

Tags: angular, npm, single-page-application, visual-studio-2022

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyaLi.jpg)I am creating an Angular project in VS 2022 and when I run it, I get the following error

Error: Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'.
Information: No SPA development server running at https://localhost:44463 found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in most of the cases this can be for node version  that you installed,check angular version compatability with node version from here:[Is there a compatibility list for Angular / Angular-CLI and Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the node version 18.14.0 and I switched to version 18.10.0 and it worked.

Comment: you got it ,goodluck 