# Angular and NodeJS version conflict

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-upgrade

I have a Angular application that is currently running version 6. I am working on updating the version to at least 12. The issue I have is that the node version is 14.15.0 does this matter at the moment? Since no code changes are being done just working on dependencies, updating to each version, etc. does the node version matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technical:

You should have a look at the compatibily table here:
[Is there a compatibility list for Angular / Angular-CLI and Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js)

seems like you angular version is for node 8. Consider to upgrade your angular project to at least Angular 9 (should not be that hard depending on your project).

Answer (score 0):

Version matters.

The best place to guide the migration is to visit the:

https://update.angular.io/?v=6.0-15.0