# Unable to launch an Angular application from cmd using the ng serve command

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, mean-stack

I am trying to import and launch a project: MEAN Stack Task Manager Application from this git repository: https://github.com/Devstackr/task-manager-mean-stack

These are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Unzipped the files and stored them in D: drive of my device.
2. Opened `windows powershell` and used this command: `cd 'D:\task-manager-mean-stack-master\frontend'`
3. Once I am inside the frontend folder, I have run the command: `npm install -g @angular/cli@7.2.1`
   This is the result I got:
   [cmd after the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXkIh.png)
4. Now I run the command: `npm install`
   This is the output on cmd:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsx7r.png)
5. After this I am running the command `ng serve` to launch the application, but I am getting these errors:
   [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuQYH.png)

I have tried doing the following steps:

1. Run the command prompt: `npm install node-sass`
2. I again try running the command: `ng serve`
   I end up getting this error message:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGflh.png)
3. I run the command: `ng version`
   This is the output:
   [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b9gu.png)
4. I run this command after this: `npm install node-sass@latest`
5. I again run this command: `ng serve`
   This is the output I am getting:
   [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7vxp.png)

Comment: It's probably a node.js incompatibility issue. Seems the project is using Angular 7. Try running the `node --version` and see if it aligns with [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js). If not, install compatible node.js version or use some version manager like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is with the node-sass and sass-loader version compatibility.

Suggestion: Never pollute the global space always have it local as dev-dependency.

Try below code:

```
node install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader
```

If the issue still persists

1. Update the NodeJS version,
2. Delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file

run below command in the project folder.

```
npm i
```

Comment: I finally solved the problem last evening. All the while I was using npm install node-sass. Using npm install sass solved the problem. Thank you for taking the time to respond!