# LTS in Angular (Q may have been asked before!)

Tags: node.js, angular

Hi there I'm new here and to Angular. I need it for my masters. I'm encountering an error with the command ng serve. This Q may have been asked before but I could really use a quick answer:

Node.js version v19.8.1 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production.
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.

I have Angular and its components already installed in my Mac M1 Ventura. What could I be doing wrong? And if I need to reinstall Node, which version please? This site doesn't give me the info I need: https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule

Many thanks!
N

Uninstalled and reinstalled Node. I want to be able to see the host 4200 while working on VS

Comment: looks like your angular cli version is not compatible with node version. can you tell your angular-cli version here? to see angular cli version just type "ng version".

Comment: Here is a similar question where you can find which Node.js verisons are supported by which Angular versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js

Comment: Seems like you're running "ng serve" command on wrong folder, please navigate to proper folder, after doing ls command on terminal you should see src and other folder and files then it is correct place to run "ng serve" command.

Comment: @shashanksharma Thanks, I checked and got these: ACLI v15.2.6, Node.js v19.8.1, RJXS v7.8.0, TS v4.9.4 and the release link above doesn't have ACLI v15.2.6 and Node v.19.8.1.

Comment: @PrashantSingh Yeah, I got it to work somehow. Can see the src files, etc. now. Thanks.