# npm start not working upon node version update to latest in my local machine

Tags: node.js, angular

```
Node.js version v21.0.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production
```

this error is showing up in the terminal, how to make it work.

it is an angular project.

Answer (score 0):

Your angular version should be compatible to certain node version. The most LTS node version only support to some extent. For me currently, latest angular version 15 is compatible with node version ^14.20.0 || ^16.13.0 || ^18.10.0 (all with LTS) or latest.

For the Reference check out [Compatibility of Angular and node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js)

Source : Check out full list of compatibility among various version of angular, node, typescript and rxjs on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3)